# Gatling receive from websocket forever

Tags: java, websocket, performance-testing, load-testing, gatling

I have a web application that allows clients to establish websocket connection on it and subscribe to different topics.
Whenever an event happens on a topic, the server pushes a notification message of the event to all subscribed clients.

From the client perspective, each client connects to the websocket, sends some messages to subscribe to the desired topics and then listen to the websocket forever whether the server pushes any message or not.

The rate of events on the server side is on my control, then I want to measure the rate of messages received by the clients.

Is it possible to define this scenario with Gatling?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`forever` is not possible.
Gatling's WebSocket DSL expects you to define the number of expected messages, see https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/websocket/#set-a-check.

```
exec(ws("Send").sendText("hello")
  .await(15).on(wsCheck1)
  .await(15).on(wsCheck2)
  ...
  .await(15).on(wsCheck10000)
);
```

You can create that many checks with a method and a loop, but it has to be a finite loop with a fixed number of iterations.

Comment: Thanks. Now, I have written a scenario with 4 awaits and injected 50 virtual users. Gatling just reports 50 response times. I have three questions:
1. What are these 50 response times? It seems that they are the periods have taken for each user connect to the websocket. Isn't it?
2. I get `Failed to build request: Couldn't fetch open webSocket 50 (100.0%)` but all of my request are marked as OK. What does it mean?
I think that the problem is with `exec`. Because the issue is resolved if I comment out `exec(ws("Send")...)`. Whould you please help me to write a complete scenario?

Comment: 3. How should I measure and report 4*50 periods that each user has waited to get each message from server?

Comment: Stackoverflow is neither a chat nor a forum. You should switch to Gatling’s community forum for discussions.